# How can I specify the type of returned value to the type of object.propertyName from a function that takes a property name of an object as parameter

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

```
type SomeType = {
  num: number,
  str: string
}

type NullableSomeType = {
  [key in keyof SomeType]: SomeType[key] | null
}

const getValue = (propertyName: keyof SomeType, objectA: NullableSomeType, objectB: SomeType) => {
  return objectA[propertyName] || objectB[propertyName] as ???WHAT_CAN_I_WRITE_HERE???
}
```

Typescript says the assumed type of the returned value from `getValue(propertyName)` function is `num | string`, but I am sure that it can be determined by the `propertyName`. Is there a way to tell typescript the correct type, like `typeof SomeType[propertyName]` ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [In TypeScript, what do "extends keyof" and "in keyof" mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57337598/in-typescript-what-do-extends-keyof-and-in-keyof-mean)

Comment: Also `NullableSomeType` is most likely redundant. You can achieve almost the same effect using `Partial<SomeType>` – the only difference is the keys will all be made potentially `undefined` instead of potentially `null` (like in your case).

Answer (score 2):

To get TypeScript to know the type at compile time, you need to add a type parameter to the function

A definiton of `getValue` that does what you want would be

```js
const getValue = <TKey extends keyof SomeType>(
  propertyName: TKey,
  objectA: NullableSomeType,
  objectB: SomeType
): SomeType[TKey] => {
  return (objectA[propertyName] || objectB[propertyName]) as SomeType[TKey]
}
```

TypeScript will be able to infer the type parameter, so you do not have to specify it explicitly.

```js
const a: NullableSomeType = { num: 15, str: null }
const b: SomeType = { num: 20, str: "foo" }


const numVal = getValue("num", a, b);  // inferred to be of type `number`
const strVal = getValue("str", a, b);  // inferred to be of type `string`
```